# awk doesn't assign variable and uses $0 instead

Tags: awk

I'm using the following `/bin/sh` code to parse the output of `apt show` and print only the names of the packages matching the second pattern, but it doesn't work. Instead it outputs the pattern itself in both `print`s as if the variable `pac` was never assigned and instead uses `$0` in all cases.

```
apt show vim peazip 2> /dev/null | \
  awk '
    /^Package:/ {
      pac = substr($0, 10);
      print "found name "$pac;
    }
    /APT-Sources: \/var\/lib\/dpkg\/status/ {
      print "bingo "$pac;
    }
  '
```

Output: (gawk on Ubuntu)

```
found name Package: vim
found name Package: peazip:i386
bingo APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do not put the $ in front of the var name :).

Comment: try using the pac variable without the `$` sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is C-like in that you don't use `$` to get the value of a variable:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { x=42; print x }'
42
```

I think of `$` in awk as an *operator* that fetches the value of the field number identified by the **expression** after $. For example, the 2nd field is `$2`, the last field is `$NF` where NF is a variable whose value is the number of fields in the current record.

Now, why does `$pac` act like `$0`?

awk, in a numeric context, treats an arbitrary string like this: take the string, truncate it at the first non-digit character; if the truncation results in an empty string, numerically treat the string as zero.

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk '{x="2cats"; print $x}'
bar
```

The value of `pac` does not start with digits, so numerically is has value zero, then you apply the `$` "operator" to get `$0`, or the whole string

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk '{x="no-cats"; print $x}'
foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk does not require `$` in front of variable names :) your code should look like this instead:

```
apt show vim peazip 2> /dev/null | \
  awk '
    /^Package:/ {
      pac = substr($0, 10);
      print "found name "pac;
    }
    /APT-Sources: \/var\/lib\/dpkg\/status/ {
      print "bingo "pac;
    }
  '
```